# Write a TypeORM @Transaction method, when use this method the IDE report error as "Invalid number of arguments, expect 2"

Tags: transactions, visual-studio-code, ide, webstorm, typeorm

I write a Transaction method as typeorm offical document(https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/decorator-reference.md#transaction-transactionmanager-and-transactionrepository)

the code is below:

```
@Transaction('some-db-connection')
public async savePhoto(record: DeepPartial<Photo>, 
                       @TransactionManager() manager: EntityManager) {
    return await manager.save<DeepPartial<Photo>>(record)
}
```

When I use this method in some where as below:

```
await someRepo.savePhoto(record)
```

Both VS Code and WebStorm report error as "Invalid number of arguments, expect 2". Can anyone knows how to let IDE do not report this error? Thanks!

P.S.

Although IDE report error, the code can be execute without error

All my code are TypeScript code in .ts files

Comment: your `savePhoto()` method is declared to have 2 non-optional  parameters, but called with a single argument. So the errors are correct. You can make `manager` optional in code (`manager?`), or use JSDoc annotations

Comment: Hi lena, If I use manager?, I must wrap "await someRepo.savePhoto(record)" with if (manager) as below:  if (manager) { await someRepo.savePhoto(record)
 }, otherwise IDE (or TypeScript compiler) will give error: manager possible not defined. Could you give a JSDoc annotation example for me, Thanks!

Comment: I add the doc comment as, but can not resolve the IDE error warning /**
   * @param {EntityManager=} [manager=someManager]
   */

Answer (score 1):

Many of my service methods accept an optional EntityManager with a default of `getManager()`. This way, the calling method can decide if everything should be wrapped in a transaction or not. No decorators needed.

```
import { getManager, getConnection } from "typeorm"

async function savePhoto(photo: Photo, manager = getManager()): Promise<Photo> {
  return manager.save(photo)
}

async function savePhotoWithTransaction(photo: Photo): Promise<Photo> {
  return getConnection().transaction((manager) => {
    // do some other stuff inside the transaction
    return savePhoto(photo, manager)
  })
}

async function savePhotoWithoutTransaction(photo: Photo): Promise<Photo> {
  return savePhoto(photo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions work for me:

- Make 2nd argument optional should works fine, as already mentioned.

  ```
  @Transaction()
  public async savePhoto(
      photo: Photo, 
      @TransactionManager() manager?: EntityManager
  ): Promise<Photo> {
      return manager.save(photo);
  }
  ```
- Also, you can suppress errors in your .ts files

  ```
  // @ts-ignore
  await savePhoto(photo);
  ```

Comment: I feel like your second option is not a viable option, this will require to add a @ts-ignore everytime we use the function (or any of our database service).

The first option you propose lack of a "?" before calling the "save" method.
Since you stated that manager could be undefined, when using it TS will raise you an error saying that it could be undefined therefore calling ".save" could not be done risk free.